# Approximate the function $\int_0^{1/2}x^{2}\ln(1+x^2)dx$ by 4 terms

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, power-series, approximation

The Function: $\int_0^{1/2}x^{2}\ln(1+x^2)dx$

So I tried approximating it doing the following.
First, I figured out that  the series of $\ln(1+x^2)$ is just  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+2}}{n+1}$. I've gotten it by taking the derivative of $\ln(1+x^2)$ and translated that into the geometric form of a series, and integrated that.

Now, I don't quite understand what allows me to simply take the first 4 terms and multiply them by $x^2$ to get the approximation I wanted (and obviously evaluating the bounds later). What allows us to completely ignore the fact that we haven't done anything with $x^2$ that we're simply allowed to use it on our end result now as is?

Would really appreciate some explanation, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the exercise asks you is to approximate the integrand function and then compute the integral of the approximation. Since an infinite series will be involved, you just take the first four terms of that series.

$$\int_0^{0.5} x^2\ln(1+x^2)\ \text{d}x = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\int_0^{0.5} x^{2n+4}\ \text{d}x = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\frac{2^{-2 k-5}}{2 k+5}$$

The first four terms of the series are thence

$$\frac{1}{160} -\frac{1}{1792} +\frac{1}{13824} -\frac{1}{90112} = \frac{3185513}{553512960} \approx 0.00575508(...)$$

Notice that

$$\int_0^{0.5} x^2\ln(1+x^2)\ \text{d}x = \frac{1}{72} \left(22+\ln \left(\frac{125}{64}\right)-48 \arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) =  0.0057548(...)$$

**Final Remark**

$x^2$ is a polynomial function, and for that reason it cannot be approximated with a power series, like Taylor series, in the same way you do for non polynomial function.

Comment: Yeah I do understand the logic behind taking the first 4 terms of a series to get the approximation. I just don't understand the part where we multiply our end result by $x^2$ after figuring the first 4 terms of just a part of the integrand, namely $ln(1+x^2)$

Comment: EDIT: So for polynomial functions we simply take those parts and multiply them by terms of the series we've gotten from the non polynomial functions without caring about integrating them or doing anything with them other than take the bounds as is?

Comment: @JakeDrone It is a way to do. Consider this other variant, with which you can have fun: your function can be written as

$$f(x) = x^2g(x)$$

Where $g(x) = \ln(1+x^2)$. If now yo want to use Taylor series on this "new" function, you will obtain

$$f(x) = g(0) x^2+x^3 g'(0)+\frac{1}{2} x^4 g''(0)+\frac{1}{6} g^{(3)}(0) x^5+O\left(x^6\right)$$

In your case

$$f(x) = x^2\ln(1+x^2) \approx x^4-\frac{x^6}{2}+O\left(x^8\right)$$

So in this "variant" you obtain a complete polynomial function without ignoring any term. 

By the way:

$$\int_0^{1/2} x^4-\frac{x^6}{2} = 0.00569196(..)$$

Comment: @JakeDrone Let me eventually stress my last comment a bit.

I said

$$f(x) = g(0)x^2 + x^3g'(0) + \frac{1}{2}x^4 g''(0) + ..$$

But look at this... Let's collect $x^2$:

$$f(x) = x^2\left(g(0) + xg'(0) + \frac{1}{2}x^2 g''(0) + ...\right)$$

Wait: isn't this just the normal Taylor series for $g(x)$? Yes it is!

So this is why you have no problems in "ignoring" the $x^2$ term, and multiply it later by the approximated function!

Comment: @JakeDrone For convergent alternating series, if you sum $n$ terms, the error is less than the $n+1$th term, in abs value. In this case the error is less than $\frac{1}{532480}\approx 1.8\times 10^{-6}$ which means that $5$ decimals are correct